# Globbing patterns in selenium

Tags: selenium, phpunit, glob

1) "glob:at row [0-9]"  does not match "at row 7"
2) "glob:at row *"  does match "at row 7"

Why does "glob:at row [0-9]" not match "at row 7"? How do I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

glob patterns only recognize two wildcard characters: `*` (zero or more of anything) and `?` (one of anything).  To do what you want, you need to use `regexp:`, not `glob:`.